Identifying an old Sci-Fi movie with a flying hand that kills people
I saw this movie once at my Grandma's house, probably in the late 90's early 00's on what was most likely the Sci-Fi channel.  Unfortunately, I don't know any of the actors or actresses, and I only remember snippets.  Also, I saw it a long time ago, and I'm not sure if all of the snippets I remember actually happened or if my imagination filled in some gaps. However, I'd really like to know if this movie exists, or if anyone else remembers it, because I really hope my imagination isn't that crazy.
As I recall, the movie includes a flying hand that has a mouth on its middle finger that it can use to kill people.  Additionally, it can latch onto people's faces and turn them into chickens, which then inhabit this woman's business. If anyone can verify that this was a real thing, I would very much appreciate it!

I believe the mouth was at the end of the finger, but this was a long time ago so who can be for sure.  If you can find a clip of a hand flying through the air and latching to a dude's face to gore him, that's probably it, regardless of the mouth's location.
If I remember right, the hand latches to the face, and then these black strings come out and the guy kind of slouches off camera.  I got the insinuation that he became a chicken, and that's why there were so many chickens, but maybe it just killed him and his body disappeared under the multitude of chickens already present?

Sounds like Netherworld from 1992. It's pretty much a horror film, though.

A young man arrives at his father's mansion in Louisiana to discover that a secretive cult is using winged creatures to raise the dead to do their bidding.

The movie featured a flying voodoo stone hand with a mouth on its middle finger that turned people... into huge birds? Or transferred souls into birds? Something in the vicinity, anyway. It's a weird one. ;) Here's the trailer:




Between the gore and nudity in the trailer, that seems like a movie I'd watch. And then quickly never admit to watching ever.

Crud, there's gore and nudity? Just glanced at it to refresh my memory. I'll put up a warning. EDIT: Actually, it's not that bad. There seems to be a more NSFW trailer out there; that's the safer one.

Sweet blithering Jesus, there's a lot of really bad cinema out there!

@JohnnyBones And then some. :/

Wow!  That's it!  Thank you!  I'm glad I'm not crazy (well, for this particular reason anyway)!  Thanks Walt!
